Failed to complete openAI chat API with openAI SDK
I am trying to build an assistant with OpenAI. Everything is complete but when I am trying to make a conversation it's throwing an error.
My index.js file:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const { OpenAI } = require('openai');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies

// Initialize the OpenAI API client with your API key
const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
const openaiClient = new OpenA`your text`I(apiKey);

// API endpoint to ask the assistant a question
app.post('/ask', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { question } = req.body;
        const response = await openaiClient.complete({
            engine: "davinci", // Adjust this based on the engine you want to use
            prompt: question,
            max_tokens: 150,
        });
        const assistantReply = response.data.text.trim();

        res.json({ reply: assistantReply });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error asking question:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to ask question' });
    }
});

// Start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

The error that was thrown:
Error asking question: TypeError: openaiClient.complete is not a function
    at /Users/md.golamrabbani/Desktop/ai-assisnt/index.js:18:45

